# Does anyone know how to "clean up" this monstrosity

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am creating an app using React Native in JavaScript.

I have this code.

```
            let ScoretoStore = (parseInt(TeamAShot) + "A")

            if (End === 2){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 3){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 4){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 5){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 6){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 7){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 8){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 9){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 10){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 11){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 12){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 13){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 14){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 15){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 16){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 17){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 18){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 19){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 20){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 21){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,
                    found.ScoreEnd20,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 22){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,
                    found.ScoreEnd20,found.ScoreEnd21,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 23){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,
                    found.ScoreEnd20,found.ScoreEnd21,found.ScoreEnd22,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 24){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,
                    found.ScoreEnd20,found.ScoreEnd21,found.ScoreEnd22,found.ScoreEnd23,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 25){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,
                    found.ScoreEnd20,found.ScoreEnd21,found.ScoreEnd22,found.ScoreEnd23,found.ScoreEnd24,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 26){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,
                    found.ScoreEnd20,found.ScoreEnd21,found.ScoreEnd22,found.ScoreEnd23,found.ScoreEnd24,found.ScoreEnd25,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 27){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,
                    found.ScoreEnd20,found.ScoreEnd21,found.ScoreEnd22,found.ScoreEnd23,found.ScoreEnd24,found.ScoreEnd25,
                    found.ScoreEnd26,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 28){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,
                    found.ScoreEnd20,found.ScoreEnd21,found.ScoreEnd22,found.ScoreEnd23,found.ScoreEnd24,found.ScoreEnd25,
                    found.ScoreEnd26,found.ScoreEnd27,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 29){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,
                    found.ScoreEnd20,found.ScoreEnd21,found.ScoreEnd22,found.ScoreEnd23,found.ScoreEnd24,found.ScoreEnd25,
                    found.ScoreEnd26,found.ScoreEnd27,found.ScoreEnd28,ScoretoStore)
            } else if (End === 30){
                updateScores(ID,found.ScoreEnd1,found.ScoreEnd2,found.ScoreEnd3,found.ScoreEnd4,found.ScoreEnd5,
                    found.ScoreEnd6,found.ScoreEnd7,found.ScoreEnd8,found.ScoreEnd9,found.ScoreEnd10,
                    found.ScoreEnd11,found.ScoreEnd12,found.ScoreEnd13,found.ScoreEnd14,
                    found.ScoreEnd15,found.ScoreEnd16,found.ScoreEnd17,found.ScoreEnd18,found.ScoreEnd19,
                    found.ScoreEnd20,found.ScoreEnd21,found.ScoreEnd22,found.ScoreEnd23,found.ScoreEnd24,found.ScoreEnd25,
                    found.ScoreEnd26,found.ScoreEnd27,found.ScoreEnd28,found.ScoreEnd29,ScoretoStore)
```

I don't think further context is needed, but if it is required, please let me know.
How do I clean it up. By that I mean how do I use loops to turn this into maybe a 10 lines piece of code. An exact answer would be appreciated, because I have already tried solving it myself.

Alright, some more context.
The "End" here is referring to round. Like a round in a game.
"found" comes from this:

```
const found = ScoresState.find(obj => {
        return obj.id === ID;
    });
```

And here is the ScoresState array in item context.

```
const ScoresReducer = (ScoresState,ScoresAction) => {
    switch(ScoresAction.type){
        case actionTypes.createScores:
            return [
                ...ScoresState,
                {
                    id: ID,
                    ScoreEnd1: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd1,
                    ScoreEnd2: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd2,
                    ScoreEnd3: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd3,
                    ScoreEnd4: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd4,
                    ScoreEnd5: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd5,
                    ScoreEnd6: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd6,
                    ScoreEnd7: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd7,
                    ScoreEnd8: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd8,
                    ScoreEnd9: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd9,
                    ScoreEnd10: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd10,
                    ScoreEnd11: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd11,
                    ScoreEnd12: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd12,
                    ScoreEnd13: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd13,
                    ScoreEnd14: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd14,
                    ScoreEnd15: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd15,
                    ScoreEnd16: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd16,
                    ScoreEnd17: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd17,
                    ScoreEnd18: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd18,
                    ScoreEnd19: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd19,
                    ScoreEnd20: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd20,
                    ScoreEnd21: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd21,
                    ScoreEnd22: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd22,
                    ScoreEnd23: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd23,
                    ScoreEnd24: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd24,
                    ScoreEnd25: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd25,
                    ScoreEnd26: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd26,
                    ScoreEnd27: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd27,
                    ScoreEnd28: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd28,
                    ScoreEnd29: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd29,
                    ScoreEnd30: ScoresAction.payload.ScoreEnd30,
                }
        ];
        case actionTypes.updateScores:
            return ScoresState.map((e) => {
                if (e.id === ScoresAction.payload.id){
                    return ScoresAction.payload;                    
                } else {
                    return e;
                }
            });
        default:
            return ScoresState;
    };
};
```

Here is the updateScores function.

```
const updateScores = (id,ScoreEnd1,ScoreEnd2,ScoreEnd3,ScoreEnd4,ScoreEnd5,ScoreEnd6,ScoreEnd7,ScoreEnd8,ScoreEnd9,ScoreEnd10,
        ScoreEnd11,ScoreEnd12,ScoreEnd13,ScoreEnd14,ScoreEnd15,ScoreEnd16,ScoreEnd17,ScoreEnd18,ScoreEnd19,ScoreEnd20,ScoreEnd21,ScoreEnd22,ScoreEnd23,
        ScoreEnd24,ScoreEnd25,ScoreEnd26,ScoreEnd27,ScoreEnd28,ScoreEnd29,ScoreEnd30,callback) => {
            dispatchSE({type: actionTypes.updateScores, payload:{id,ScoreEnd1,ScoreEnd2,ScoreEnd3,ScoreEnd4,ScoreEnd5,ScoreEnd6,ScoreEnd7,ScoreEnd8,ScoreEnd9,ScoreEnd10,
            ScoreEnd11,ScoreEnd12,ScoreEnd13,ScoreEnd14,ScoreEnd15,ScoreEnd16,ScoreEnd17,ScoreEnd18,ScoreEnd19,ScoreEnd20,ScoreEnd21,ScoreEnd22,ScoreEnd23,
            ScoreEnd24,ScoreEnd25,ScoreEnd26,ScoreEnd27,ScoreEnd28,ScoreEnd29,ScoreEnd30}});
        if (callback) callback();
    };
```

I would also like to mention the code works perfectly fine as is.

Comment: Yes, further context is needed. We have no idea have the `found` object is created, for instance. If so, we might tell you to make a property on that object named `scoreEnd` that stores an array of the values that are now in `ScoreEnd1`, `ScoreEnd2`, etc. and pass that to `updateScores`...

Comment: This question is not showing enough effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `found` object is badly formatted. Rather than having properties `ScoreEnd1`, `ScoreEnd2`, etc, you should fix whatever's generating it so that it has an array of `ScoreEnd` values instead. Then all you need to do is slice the array from 0 to `End` and spread it into the argument list.

```
const scoreEnds = found.ScoreEnd.slice(0, End - 1);
const ScoretoStore = parseInt(TeamAShot) + "A";
updateScores(ID, ...scoreEnds, ScoretoStore);
```

You could convert the malformed object into an array yourself with something like

```
const scoreEnds = Array.from(
  { length: 30 },
  (_, i) => found['ScoreEnd' + (i + 1)]
);
```

but it'd be better to fix things so that the bad data structure isn't created in the first place.

It looks like your `updateScores` function has problems too. Since it's under your control, instead of having so many separate arguments, have just a single one for the `ScoreEnd`s.

```
const updateScores = (id, ScoreEnds, callback) => {
  dispatchSE({type: actionTypes.updateScores, payload:{id, ScoreEnds });
  if (callback) callback();
};
```

And change the `ScoresReducer` so that it also doesn't have so many individual properties, and uses the array instead - and the same for any other user of the `ScoreEnd` state in your app.

Comment: Hi can you please take another look at my questions thanks.

Comment: Oops forgot to tick.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `found.ScoreEndN` to `found.ScoreEnd[n]` (an array).

Then you can do a for loop

```js
for(let i = 2; i < 30; i++){
    if(End == i) updateScores(ID, ...found.ScoreEnd.filter((el, index) => index < i), ScoretoStore);
}
```